# $cordovaPush:notificationReceived called two times

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, push-notification, ionic-framework

i'm working on a ionic app and i need the push notifications , so all works fine i can receive the notification using ionic push notification , but the call back is called twice and i receive just one notification .

here is my code:

```
// the call back     
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {});

// the push service registration 
$ionicPush.register({
          canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
          canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
          canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
          canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
          onNotification: function(notification) {
            // Handle new push notifications here
            //$rootScope.$broadcast('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived',notification);
            return true;


          }
        });
```

thanks

Comment: Are you using a database to hold the device tokens or giving them manually for each push? @haffanehatim

Comment: for now i just add it manually for test notifications fron ionic.io , but they will be saved on a database for the production